# JSON array push array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have a JSON structure as so:

```
[
    {
        "name": "Sam",
        "ride": "My Ride test",
        "session": "6htbgumjtmnxko6r",
        "info": null
    },
]
```

I wish to append data into the `"info"` part of the structure. my variables look like so:

```
var jsonData = [{                                   
    "name": "Sam",                                  
    "ride": "My Ride test",                         
    "session": session,                             
    "info": null
}];
jsonData.info = [];
```

I have tried:

```
jsonData.info.push({
        id: integer, 
        data:   { 
            distance: currentDistance || 0,
            lat: lat, 
            lon: lon
            } 
});
    jsonData.push(jsonData.info);

jsonData[3].push(jsonData.info);
```

All the above have resulted in is:

```
[
    {
        "name": "Sam",
        "ride": "My Ride test",
        "session": "6htbgumjtmnxko6r",
        "info": null
    },
    [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "data": {
                "distance": 0,
                "lat": 53.6419743,
                "lon": -1.7945115999999999
            }
        }
    ]
]
```

How would I go about pushing into the `"info"` section of my jsonData?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
jsonData[0].info = {
    id: integer, 
    data:   { 
        distance: currentDistance || 0,
        lat: lat, 
        lon: lon
        } 
}
```

`jsonData` is an array, `info` is not a property of the array itself, just of the first value in the array.

If you wanted to add this to each value in array you would do something like:

```
jsonData.foreEach(function(v){ 
    v.info = {
        ...
    }
})
```

[Where `forEach` is supported on all browsers > IE8](http://kangax.github.io/es5-compat-table/).

Comment: Wow, wasn't thinking straight at all and completely missed that, thank you, because you answered first and provide a detailed answer I will mark your answer as correct, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You could try:

```
jsonData[0].info = {
        id: integer, 
        data:   { 
            distance: currentDistance || 0,
            lat: lat, 
            lon: lon
        } 
}
```

Comment: -1 Since it's the same answer as http://stackoverflow.com/a/22824437/2615737 and that one was posted first.

Comment: @FranciscoCorrales I appreciate it but he probably started typing his before mine was up.

Comment: @FranciscoCorrales Yeah he beat me by 14 seconds, there was no answer when i posted it.

Comment: Ok, I trust you, so no -1 for you. But the +1 goes to him.